# vector multiply question to prove

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-writing, vectors

in the beginning I want to know some answers to this question: if $u, v \in \mathbb{R^{n}}$, show that if $|u+v|^{2}=|u|^{2}+|v|^{2}$, then $u\bullet v=0$. I think this one is showing how u or v is =0. I made the first step to be let u=0. Then I can prove this for u. Then I do v=0, and then prove it same as u.

Comment: There are other values for $u,v$ other than $0$ where $|u+v|^{2}=|u|^{2}+|v|^{2}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recall that $\vert x+y\vert^2 = (x+y)\bullet(x+y)$. Now use the fact that $+$ is distributive over $\bullet$: $$\vert x + y\vert^2 = (x+y)\bullet(x+y) = x\bullet x + 2x\bullet y + y\bullet y = \vert x\vert^2 + \vert y\vert^2 + 2x\bullet y.$$
The only chance that this equation holds is iff $x\bullet y = 0$.